# Multiple instances of Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to have multiple instances of the Autodesk Forge Viewer (v6.2) running on my page, but hidden in tabs.

As the user switches tabs it will hide and show the viewer with a loaded model.

While I have this working, any hidden instances that have loaded a model break on events (E.g resize event), giving an error like:

```
VM19014 viewer3D.min.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__webglFramebuffer' of null
    at k.initFrameBufferMRT (VM19014 viewer3D.min.js:53)
```

I have looked at `.tearDown()` and `finish()` but they seem to completely unload the model in the viewer, slowing the experience for the user.

Is there a way to pause the viewer if it's not visible?

**Edit:**

I've accepted the answer below as it is a correct solution and probably one I would go for if I was re-doing the page.

In the end, I went for a different workaround where I moved the entire tab content offscreen so the canvas is still live in the DOM and it doesn't jump my content around:

```
  .tab-content {
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way to suspend the initialization of the viewer. It can only be initialized with non-zero-size canvas. You could try hiding the multiple instances of the viewer using `z-index` instead of `display:none` so that they all get a non-empty canvas and are initialized properly.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. In the end, I went for moving the tab content offscreen, which I don't think is the best solution, but quickest in my case. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `z-index` setting `visibility` to `hidden` also works well:

```
#MyViewerDiv {visibility: hidden;}
```

Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/bp9dycrt/

Comment: Thanks. The issue in my case with `visibility: hidden` is that I needed to set `display: block` first on the entire tab content, which messed with the entire layout of the page. A quicker solution for me was to move the entire content offscreen - see my edit above.

Comment: But isn’t your tab content absolutely positioned and taken off the flow already? Shouldn’t mess with other elements regardless of its display value. See https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/epk9o40g