# Query properties using the forge-viewer library without rendering model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the forge-viewer library to display models. I'm wondering if it is possible to at the same time query properties from another model, without rendering the other model or altering the state of the original viewer instance?

Preferably by obtaining a new instance of Autodesk.Viewing.Model, in order to use methods like `model.getProperties(...)`.

Loading with the original viewer instance causes the other model to display in the browser

```
const document: Autodesk.Viewing.Document = await myLoadDocumentFunction("urn:another-model-urn");
const defaultModel = document.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
const model = await viewer.loadDocumentNode(document, defaultModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states, the `options` input variable for [loadDocumentNode()](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loaddocumentnode-avdocument-manifestnode-options) is passed on to [loadModel()](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) so you can check the documentation of that function to see what options are available.

One of them is `loadAsHidden` which seems to do exactly what you need:

[image]

FYI: it should also be possible to create another `Viewer` instance, make it invisible (e.g. placing it off the screen) and load extra models there: [Multiple instances of Autodesk Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042518/multiple-instances-of-autodesk-forge-viewer)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, even when using `loadDocumentNode` with the `loadAsHidden` option, the original model is replaced by a loading spinner. I suppose placing another viewer instance off screen could be a workaround though.

Comment: Did you add the `keepCurrentModels: true` option?
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this option. It does seem to work as intended. I wonder why it is left out of the documentation though.

Comment: Ha! You're right, it's missing. I'll get someone to add it!
Thanks for confirming it works OK! 